# Ubuntu Data disk

Tags: partitioning, preferences

OK, Win 7 / Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot system.   OS on ssd drive. 300GB partition on HDD set aside for Ubuntu data.

Q; How do I set up HDD partition as default for downloads & storage so as not to 
use up ssd space? I am assuming this will take Terminal commands, or can this be done in set up?
Thanks

Comment: You can mount your /home to HDD, or manually set default directories in ubuntu (see this question: Change the default Downloads directory)

Comment: To see details of your existing partitions run `lsblk -o name,partlabel,fstype,mountpoint,size` and post output into question.

Comment: You can have some or all of the normal data folders like Documents, Downloads, Music, etc in data partition(s) and link back into /home. Then system  & you see it as the same as install, but data actually on other drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk